# Azure Data Factory - Copy Data from PostgreSQL DB on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, azure-data-factory

Trying to copy data from **PostgreSQL** DB on an Ubuntu box that needs IPs whitelisted to access it. With **Azure Data Factory** IPs changing all the time and since i cannot install **Self-hosted integration runtime** as its a **Linux** server, what other options are available to be able to copy data from this PostgreSQL DB into an Azure SQL DB without having to worry about the IP addresses. Any suggestions or known solutions for this please?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime),ADF Self-hosted integration runtime can't be installed on the linux server,only could be used on the windows server.

BTW,this feature will also not be supported recently,please follow this feedback [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/35520787-create-self-hosted-integration-runtime-capable-of).

> the latest comment:Currently we don't have any plan on this yet. Could
>   you share us your reasons why do you want Linux?

As workaround,i suggest you get an idea of Azure DMS(Database Migration Service). Please see more detail about it from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-postgresql-azure-postgresql-online) and this [video](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/how-to-migrate-postgresql-to-azure-postgresql-online-dms-and-cli/).

Comment: Thanks Jay! But we need to pull data on a daily basis from this database and not a one time migration. Trying to find alternate options

Comment: @DB1 You're welcome! I notice that DMS is based on the azure cli commands. I think you could write cli commands as script and execute it in linux cron:https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux

Comment: @DB1 If you think my answer is beneficial for you,would you please mark it as answer?Thank you.